# how to set the checkbox in the listview to the right?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have used the below code for the view in the list view and I want to set the checkbox to the right but it is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Comment: It's not enough information about your program. Show us your custom listview adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout_width to wrap content

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change that to the `RelativeLayout` and change `layout_width` to `wrap_content`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/textView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#000000"/>
     <CheckBox
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:checked="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:textColor="#000000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the width of your checkbox to `wrap_content`?

If you can, then try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Or even this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`CheckedTextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html). That has the check mark on right. [Here](http://puneetaggarwal.in/android/checkedtextview/) or [here](http://blog.rochdev.com/2011/08/checkedtextview.html) are 2 googled examples on how to use. This way you'll only need one View to use, not 2 as you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```